# how do I iterate through a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through a list of list and record all possible combinations within the list from left to right. The first list is always going to be the first position of the combination, the second list will be the second position, and etc.

How would I get all possible combinations of the letters assuming that the first list is the same letter always. So far my code does isolate the first set but I am having trouble appending the rest onto the list to create the combinations.

```
listoflists = [[a,b,c,d][e,f,g][h,i]]

for i in range(len(listoflists[]):
    for j in range(len(listoflists[i])):
        if(i==0):
            print(listoflists[i][j])
            newlist[i].append([listoflists[i][j]])
        else:
            print(i)
            print(listoflists[i][j])
            #newlist[[i[j]].append([listoflists[i][j]])
```

The last line of code throws an error and the print statement are there for debugging. So how exactly would i get all the combinations of the list of lists using for loops

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand exactly what you want, could you edit your question to be clearer? As a general answer, you're probably looking for something already provided by [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). Maybe `permutations` or  `combinations`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `for i in listoflists`?

Comment: `len(listoflists[])` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: The output I expect is for example. aeh,aei,afh,afi,..etc.

Comment: I'm assuming basically you mean *aeh, aei, afh, afi* all the way through *dgi* is this correct? Now, are *aeh* and *hea* two different cominations or the same?

Comment: so the first list is always going to be the first element. So i dont need the output e,a,i for example. It will always start with the letters in the first list

Comment: ok, but you would need *aei* and also *aie*, correct? also is *ai* possible?

Comment: no I would only need aei as well as ae and just a. I only need the output from right to left from the lists.

Answer (score 1):

That process is called [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

> In mathematics, a Cartesian product is a mathematical operation which
>   returns a set (or product set or simply product) from multiple sets.
>   That is, for sets A and B, the Cartesian product A × B is the set of
>   all ordered pairs (a, b) where a ∈ A and b ∈ B.

There is already a library function in python for that, namely `itertools.product`:

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat]) Cartesian product of input
>   iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

When you apply it to your list, you get your desired result:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ll = [["a","b","c","d"], ["e","f","g"], ["h","i"]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*ll))
[('a', 'e', 'h'), ('a', 'e', 'i'), ('a', 'f', 'h'), ('a', 'f', 'i'), ('a', 'g', 'h'), ('a', 'g', 'i'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('b', 'e', 'i'), ('b', 'f', 'h'), ('b', 'f', 'i'), ('b', 'g', 'h'), ('b', 'g', 'i'), ('c', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'e', 'i'), ('c', 'f', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i'), ('c', 'g', 'h'), ('c', 'g', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'h'), ('d', 'e', 'i'), ('d', 'f', 'h'), ('d', 'f', 'i'), ('d', 'g', 'h'), ('d', 'g', 'i')]
```

Comment: ok so does the list function automatically edit the lists inputted. Im not exactly sure what to print out since when I printed ll it did not get edited

Comment: `itertools.product` returns to an iterable, `list` function doesn't print anything, it just converts an iterable to a list, and returns the list. Python REPL does the printing. When you aren't on REPL,  you can just do `for i in itertools.product(*ll): # do something with i` if you want to loop on them.